# Ionic Angularjs form fires twice with $cordovaDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am running this through Ionic live reload and for some reason when I click the Verify button, the the `identify()` function run's twice except for when I do certain things defined below.

If anyone has any suggestions, it'd be greatly appreciated.

- If I click enter, it only run's once.
- If I comment out the following code, it also only run's once

**FOLLOWING CODE IN CONTROLLER**:

```
//if(resp == false) $cordovaDialogs.alert('ID Not Found', 'Not Found', 'Try Again'); 
//else $cordovaDialogs.alert('We were not able to load up the user database.', 'Error', 'Try Again');
```

---

Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="loginBox">
    <form name="id_frm" ng-submit="id_frm.$valid && identify()" novalidate>
        <input name="id" ng-model="id" type="text" placeholder="type id number" required />
        <button name="submit" type="submit">{{ identify_button || "Verify" }}</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Identification Controller**

```
.controller('identification', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $cordovaNetwork, $cordovaDialogs, $q, $pouchDB) {

  $scope.identifying = false;

  $scope.identify = function()
  {
    if(!$scope.identifying)
    {
      $scope.identify_button = "Verifiying..";
      $scope.identifying = true;

      $q.when($pouchDB.findUser($scope.id))
      .then(function(resp){

        if(resp) {
          localStorage['id'] = $scope.id;
          $rootScope['id'] = $scope.id;
          $state.transitionTo('home');
        }
        else { 
          if(resp == false) $cordovaDialogs.alert('ID Not Found', 'Not Found', 'Try Again'); 
          else $cordovaDialogs.alert('We were not able to load up the user database.', 'Error', 'Try Again'); 

          console.log("FALSE");

          $scope.identifying = false; 
          $scope.identify_button = "Verify";
        }
      });

    }

  }

})
```

**POUCHDB SERVICE**

```
self.findUser = function(idnum) {
    return $q.when(self.db.query('filters/users'))
    .then(function(resp) {
        var found = false, found_id;
        angular.forEach(resp.rows, function(u, id) { if(u.value == idnum) { found = true; found_id = u.id; } });
        if(found) return found_id; else return false;
    })
    .catch(function(resp) { console.log(JSON.stringify(resp)); return null; })
}
```